# File system becomes read only after sudo apt upgrade

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi, read-only

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a raspberry pi 2 model b, and I am new to Ubuntu as well. I used the raspberry pi imager to install Ubuntu on a 128GB sd card, and everything goes somewhat smoothly until I try to update. I run `sudo apt update` and that works, but when I enter `sudo apt upgrade` and wait for the command to run, I come back to a wall of text saying that the file system is read only. Any help? I have tried re-installing the os multiple times, and this time, I just rebooted the pi.

Comment: Looks like your sd card is broken. Happens if you pull the power plug instead of shutting down. Could you elaborate, what you mean with "reflashing". Usually the install is done on the SD card, which can't be "flashed". Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1246588/edit) your question and add the missing information

Comment: By flash, I mean reinstalling the os. I will update the question, but is there a way to fix it?